# docker buildx - how to use different Dockerfile or switch in one

Tags: docker

I have to use two different Dockerfiles, or one if it is possible to switch on platform, one where it:

*Update: I have accepted @SamBos answer, but will add; you need to create you own manifest if you want both Dockerfiles in the same ref. tag(manifest)*

`RUN curl -LO https://...amd64`

and one where it

`RUN curl -LO https://...arm64`

How can I do that using docker buildx to become one manifest?

Comment: Those two commands seem identical? In any case you can pass build args in to  docker build(x) : https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg

Comment: Thanks, it should have ben amd and arm. And yes args might be the solution.

Comment: Do you know if using args, if it will become one manifest?

Comment: With args alone, no they will be distinct. Follow the full buildx example to build a multi arch manifest https://www.docker.com/blog/multi-arch-build-and-images-the-simple-way/

Comment: Thanks, I guess I need to use manifest and combine them afterwards using: docker manifest create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You coudl add platform as an `ARG` to your `Dockerfile`:

```
ARG PLATFORM=defaultplatform
RUN curl -LO https://...${PLATFORM}
```

and then set that from `docker build`:

```
docker build --build-arg PLATFORM=arm64
```

Comment: Since you're using the BuildKit backend, you may be able to use the `TARGETPLATFORM` ARG that [Docker provides automatically](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#predefined-args), though it's not going to be the exact syntax you show.